# Here Maps API KML format support

Tags: android, here-api

Hi i have a kml file which contains a set of polygons and i need to place these polygons on the map.
I researched API documentation but i didn't find out a method for kml format loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an open source tool such as [this](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/geotools.html) or [this](https://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak.html) to parse the KML, then render it with the MapPolygon or related MapObjects.